# Angular Guard Function Return Boolean Observable

Tags: angular, observable, guard

I need to have a route guard function read in some data from the localStorage, but because of how angular executes (from what I have read) it doesn't wait to read in the values before completing the guard function. This is why an observable is needed, which actually waits to process the data.

The problem is that all examples have a service and other extra things. I just need to read in the localStorage value. Nothing fancy at all. This will either return a observable boolean value or a UrlTree.

```
export const isValuePresentGuard: CanActivateFn = (): Observable<boolean> | UrlTree => {
    const fromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('data');
    
    if(fromLocalStorage) {
        return true;
    }

    return inject(Router).createUrlTree(['/another-page']);
};
```

I might be over thinking this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CanActivateFn` is actually defined as

```
export type CanActivateFn = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) =>
    Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree;
```

You can return `boolean|UrlTree` without any problem.

Comment: I understand that, but my function states that I am not returning an Observable<boolean> but just a boolean.   I need to convert my `return true` statement to return an observable.

Comment: remove the `: Observable<boolean> | UrlTree` typing and let the inference do its job. Defining `CanActivateFn ` is enough for safety here.

Comment: The problem is that I need an observable so it will take the time to read in the `localStorage`.  If not, then there is a race condition where it just rushes by and determines that it's always false.

Comment: `localStorage` is synchronous, no need for observables here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, How come my console.log's wont print in the guard?